# Objectlistview ignoring custom group formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have an `ObjectListView` and I'm showing groups and their corresponding item count. I need to changing the formatting so I did:

```
dlvList.GroupWithItemCountFormat = "{0} ({1} records)";
dlvList.GroupWithItemCountSingularFormat = "{0} (1 record)";
```

However, the above formatting is ignored and the default formatting keeps on being done.

Is there any other property that I need to set?

Comment: I take it you have ShowItemCountOnGroups = true; It's working for me with just those 3 lines.

Comment: @ThomasN Yes I have set it to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the group formatting at the column level, ie:

```
mycolumn.GroupWithItemCountFormat = "{0} ({1} records)";
mycolumn.GroupWithItemCountSingularFormat = "{0} (1 record)";
```

Comment: Interesting, both setting at list view and column level work for me but obviously column level overrides list level.  Is it possible the column is getting assigned the 'default' value elsewhere in your code?  Anyway glad you solved it.